# monotouch rest starter kit support?

Tags: xamarin.ios

I am trying to write my first app using mono and  monotouch, that will be a rest client app.

does monotouch supports the rest starter kit dlls(Microsoft.Http.dll) ?

which options do i have to write a rest client on monotouch ?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Hammock on [github](http://github.com/danielcrenna/hammock) also supports MonoTouch. Just clone, open Hammock.MonoTouch.sln, build, and pick it out of the /bin/mono folder in the project root.

Answer (score 0):

[RestSharp](http://restsharp.org/) on [github](https://github.com/johnsheehan/RestSharp)!